# How to match CSV value in column

Tags: php, mysql, csv

my mysql table name products.

How can get data this table.

table shema

```
id| catid |subcatid
-----------------
1 | 5     | 2,3,5


SELECT * FROM products where subcatid=2
```

not correct

how can write correct sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM products where find_in_set(2,subcatid)
```

consider to normalize your table

Comment: how can print my images  images column aa.jpg, bb.png, ccc.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please open another thread and give us more information.